# Получить одномерный массив из двумерного

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм

Как из такого массива:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => @eqor123 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => @artem156 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => @max100500) )
```

Получить такой:

```
Array ( [0] => @eqor123; [1] => @artem156; [2] => @max100500 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте array_map():

```
$arr = [
    ['@eqor123'],
    ['@artem156'],
    ['@max100500']
];

$arr = array_map(function($a){ return $a[0]; },$arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => @eqor123
    [1] => @artem156
    [2] => @max100500
)
```